# scroll to last position of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I want to scroll to last saved position of recyclerview after destroying or pausing app. I have used below code for saving related position and offset in `SharedPreferences`

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    QueryPreferences.setLastPos(getActivity(), String.valueOf(((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()));
    QueryPreferences.setLastOffset(getActivity(), String.valueOf(mRecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()));
}
```

and below code for getting position and offset and then scrolling to last position of recyclerview:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();//initialization of recyclerview and adapter
    //final int scrllPosition=Integer.parseInt(QueryPreferences.getLastPos(getActivity()));
    final int scrllOffset=Integer.parseInt(QueryPreferences.getLastOffset(getActivity()));
    mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,-scrllOffset);//scrolling down
    //I also tried mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, scrllOffset);
}
```

if I set offset equal to zero, scrolling is done without any problem (scrolls to top of an item), but when I set an offset, recyclerview scrolls to another item (not last saved item position) even with applying delay using `Handler().postDelayed`. I should note that using `computeVerticalScrollOffset()`, I got offsets as large as 73000 which implies that this offset is relative to first item (position 0). How can I correctly get the offset and scroll to desired item with correct offset? Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set LayoutManager & and scroll to particular position with the help of below code.

Just set `setStackFromEnd=true` or `setReverseLayout=true` so that LLM will layout items from end.

```
mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(yourList.size());
```

// yourList is the ArrayList that you are passing to your RecyclerView Adapter.

Comment: Thank you @Maheshwar Ligade. I have set LayoutManager in onCreateView. scrollToPosition(int pos) scrolls to top of the  particular position and offsets from top is ignored by using it.

Comment: I think you should subtract 1 from `yourList.size()` (it wasn’t my idea, [Goodlife](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5063320/goodlife) suggested it as an edit, I just didn’t think it belonged in an edit from someone who didn’t post the answer).